# replace space with underscore in expect script

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, expect, shell-builtin

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set cmd "abc def ghi lkj"
set log [ expr echo ${cmd// /_} ]
```

I would like to log variable as ghi_lkj

first I wast trying to replace all spaces with underscores and then remove first two words.

I want to do it only in expect script not shell script.

please suggest how to do. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

`expect` is a TCL interpreter, `${cmd// /_}` is a Korn shell parameter expansion operator. TCL is not ksh, or any shell for that matters.

After reading the `expect` man page, your next step should be to study the TCL documentation. See for instance https://tcl.tk/doc/ though you can also install the man pages on your system for your version of TCL (you may need to install a `tcl-doc` package).

Here to do character substitutions, you can use TCL's `string map` for instance:

```
set cmd "abc def ghi lkj"
set log [string map {" " _} $cmd]
puts $log
```

Or consider that `$cmd` as a list and join with `_`:

```
set cmd "abc def ghi lkj"
set log [join $cmd _]
puts $log
```

Which would output `abc_def_ghi_lkj`.

If you want `ghi_lkj`, then, that's not only SPC to `_` you want to do.

Possibly you want the last two words joined with `_` or all but the first 2 joined with `_`:

```
set cmd "abc def ghi lkj"
set log [join [lrange $cmd 2 end] _]
puts $log
```

Comment: Excellent advice. Generally you want to explicitly convert strings to lists before using list commands (in case the strings does not contain a valid list): `set log [join [lrange [split $cmd] 2 end] _]`

Comment: @glennjackman, true in the general case, but given the name of the variable (`cmd`), I take it it's meant to contain a list here.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly.